# how to create dynamic test case in pytest (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, pytest

lets say i have a dataframe which is returning from a module after certain computation
module name is `cmpt.py`

```
def main():
    # performing certain computation and returning a dataframe
    return df_cmpt
```

the `df_cmpt` contain data as below

```
edate,id,cap_p,cap_i,dump_p,dump_i,flag_ap
2021-03-01,101,0.124233,0.124226,0.899764,0.899264,1
2021-03-01,102,0.423322,0.423352,0.353543,0.353443,0
2021-03-01,103,0.233234,0.233234,0.747447,0.747247,1
2021-03-01,104,0.534223,0.534323,0.722727,0.722727,0
2021-03-02,104,0.124233,0.124226,0.899764,0.899264,1
2021-03-02,105,0.423322,0.423352,0.353543,0.353443,0
2021-03-02,102,0.233234,0.233234,0.747447,0.747247,1
2021-03-02,107,0.534223,0.534323,0.722727,0.722727,0
2021-03-03,401,0.124233,0.124226,0.899764,0.899264,1
2021-03-03,402,0.423322,0.423352,0.353543,0.353443,0
2021-03-03,503,0.233234,0.233234,0.747447,0.747247,1
2021-03-03,404,0.534223,0.534323,0.722727,0.722727,0
2021-03-04,131,0.124233,0.124226,0.899764,0.899264,1
2021-03-04,142,0.423322,0.423352,0.353543,0.353443,0
2021-03-04,113,0.233234,0.233234,0.747447,0.747247,1
2021-03-04,144,0.534223,0.534323,0.722727,0.722727,0
```

now i am calling this module in `test_cmpt.py`

```
import numpy as np
from compt import main as ownmain

df_cmpt = ownmain()
```

currently i am segregating  data as below

```
df_cmpt_2021-03-01_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-01') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==1)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-01') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==0)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-02_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-02') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==1)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-02_non_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-02') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==0)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-03_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-03') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==1)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-03_non_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-03') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==0)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-04_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-04') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==1)]
df_cmpt_2021-03-04_non_ap = df_cmpt[(df_cmpt['edate']=='2021-03-04') & (df_cmpt['flag_ap']==0)]
```

then creating the manual test cases

```
def test_cap_2021-03-01_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-01_ap['cap_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-01_ap['cap_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-01_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-01_ap['dump_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-01_ap['dump_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-01_non_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap['cap_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap['cap_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-01_non_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap['dump_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap['dump_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-02_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-02_ap['cap_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-02_ap['cap_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-02_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-02_ap['dump_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-02_ap['dump_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-02_non_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-02_non_ap['cap_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-02_non_ap['cap_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)

def test_cap_2021-03-02_non_ap():
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_2021-03-01_non_ap['dump_p'], df_cmpt_2021-03-02_non_ap['dump_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)
```

and so on for other dates..

now i am running pytest from consol using command `py.test -v -s --html=test_report.html capture= fd`
which is generating html report of above test cases

now what i needed, instead of manually drafting the test case i can creating them dynamically by using loops

```
ls_date = df_cmpt['edate'].unique()
ls_measure = ['cap','dump']
ls_flag = ['ap','non_ap']

for date in ls_date:
    for measure in ls_measure:
        for flag in ls_flag:
            def 'test_'+measure+'_'+date+'_'+flag():
                 np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(df_cmpt_+'date'+'_'+is_flag['cap_p'], df_cmpt_+'date'+'_'+is_flag['cap_i'], decimal=3, err_msg='', verbose=True)
```

i know this implementation is wrong but i want something like this so that i could save my manual effort of creating test case for larger dataset

Comment: it seems to me you are getting a little too granular with your tests, is there a reason you need a different test for each day?

Comment: yes actually i have high volume of data hence it help me identifying the exact error spot.

Comment: Can't you use [parametrized tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html)?